# How to match only one alphabetical word

Tags: regex, go

This is the second part of a longer regex I need to write, and somehow the "harder" half of the regex I have written works just fine. What I'm trying to achieve is a match for only alphabetic characters in one word. However, what I need to handle / desired output would be like this:

```
"abc"     // matches
"ABC"     // matches
"abc123"  // does not match
"abc[]"   // does not match
"abc abc" // does not match
```

What I've tried so far that gets close is this:

`\b[A-Za-z]+\b`

However, this somehow matches "abc[]" and also matches double words like "abc abc". Any ideas on how to achieve this? Something to note, I'm using go for this problem, which doesn't seem to support capture groups very well.

Comment: Are those the whole string? or just part of one, in which case, what is the context in which those strings occur?

Comment: I'm not sure of your question - the desired behavior is that only one word that contains only the 26 characters A-Za-z will match, anything else will be unmatched including special characters, any spaces or extra words, etc

Comment: Your problem is that unless you have some way of anchoring the regex (e.g. with `^` and `$` if the word is the whole string), the regex is free to match only part of the word, which is why you are matching `abc[]` and `abc abc`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `go`? In Python it works: `re.match(r"\b[A-Za-z]+\b", "abc abc").group(0)` -> `'abc'` and `re.match(r"\b[A-Za-z]+\b", "abc[]").group(0)` -> `'abc'`

Comment: Interesting that that works in Python.. I also can confirm the same results. Let me do a couple tests on this and I'll get back to you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, I think your regex is as simple as the following conditions:

- Any character A through Z, case insensitive, one or more times.
- Boundaries at the start and end of the line.

  ^[a-zA-Z]+$

https://regex101.com/r/lilPqT/1

Note on RegEx101.com that you can test your cases using Golang, and the full regex for Go is:

`(?m)^[a-zA-Z]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/lilPqT/1/codegen?language=golang